# PFInstallation currentInstallation clearCache

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Are we able to clear PFInstallation data forcefully?

Needed this to recreate another PFInstallation when I want to force logout a user.

Current Problem:
New Account is using PFInstallation of old account and New Account can't update the PFInstallation (clearing it when logging out).

Other Possible Solution:
Update PFInstallation's ACL through cloud code with the new account's data. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you add the ACL yourself?

Comment: @JakeT. That's the 2nd option to add the ACL and ownership to the old installation with the new user. But so far I'm having trouble with cloud code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the beforeSave trigger for the installation, check to see if the user is getting set. If so, turn off public read/write access and give read/write access to that user.  When logging out, the user should be removed, and you can return public read/write access.

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
    var installation = request.object;
    if( installation.dirty("user") ) {
        var acl = new Parse.ACL();
        var user = installation.get("user");
        if( user ) {
            acl.setPublicReadAccess(false);
            acl.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
            acl.setReadAccess(user.id, true);
            acl.setWriteAccess(user.id, true);
        }
        else {
            acl.setPublicReadAccess(true);
            acl.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
        }
        installation.setACL(acl);
    }
    response.success();
});
```

Comment: This is a good idea. It should remove the installation since it is made public and it would continue. Other than the second solution I gave. But currently, I'm having problems since the function doesn't come back to the application when I try the " if installation.dirty(----)"

Comment: Ahh I forgot to add a response.success() somewhere in there, editing it in now.

Comment: beforeSave triggers require `response.success()` to be called with an empty value in order to actually save. If you throw an error it blocks the save (used for data validation) or if you don't call success it'll time out eventually. afterSave has no success / error.

Comment: Thanks. The code works well now! I was missing this -empty value in order to save- And i was actually saving when it's already trying to save. The other problem now is the user or owner in my case isn't emptied when doing this. In my code i set them to null but it's not doing anything. (It's a pointer that is pointing to a user.)

Comment: Yeah that caught me off guard more than once! So subtle and I think it fails silently, which is awful. I'm sure it's something to do with how the object is implicitly returned by save, but I don't get why adding a value there couldn't be overridden easily instead of failing. I'm not sure why the null thing isn't working. Was gonna say something weird with the permissions, since the user has removed themselves from the object, but that'd make more sense if this was using pointer permissions. They should still be on the ACL when they perform the save to remove themselves. No guesses there, sorry